# Android:onClick not work on textView in viewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

How do I set textView onClickListener in pages of viewPage? 
  I have some pages that contain many textViews. I want to share and copy each textView when user clicks on each one but onClick does not work...
Here is my code for PagerAdapter:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 11;
}


@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    int resId=0;
    switch(position){
    case 0:resId=R.layout.one;break;
    case 1:resId=R.layout.two;break;
    case 2:resId=R.layout.three;break;
    case 3:resId=R.layout.four;break;
    case 4:resId=R.layout.five;break;
    case 5:resId=R.layout.six;break;
    case 6:resId=R.layout.seven;break;
    case 7:resId=R.layout.eight;break;
    case 8:resId=R.layout.nine;break;
    case 9:resId=R.layout.ten;break;
    case 10:resId=R.layout.eleven;break;
    }
    View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

    return view;    
    }


@Override
public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
    }


@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return arg0 == ((View) arg1);  }
```

}

and ViewPagerActivity :

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi") public class Main extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener{


ClipboardManager myClipboard;
   private ClipData myClip;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        myClipboard = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);


        Bundle getData=getIntent().getExtras();
        int position=getData.getInt("key");

        MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
        ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
        myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        myPager.setCurrentItem(position)


 }
```

Fragment(here i want set onClick to textView but doesnt work):

```
public class One extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{
TextView tv;
Main main;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.one, container, false);
    tv=(TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pageOnefirstDua);
    String text=tv.getText().toString();
    tv.setOnClickListener(this);
    return rootView;
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.pageOnefirstDua:

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Clicked: ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Fragment oncreateView is returning View not ViewGroup,
Please update this with below code and check, it should work.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.one, container, false);
    tv=(TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pageOnefirstDua);
    String text=tv.getText().toString();
    tv.setOnClickListener(this);
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: can you please let me know from where you are adding fragment in the activity. from your all three classes i cant see any place from where you are adding this fragment.

Comment: i dont add fragment in the activity i just add it to pagerAdapter :

  case 0:resId=R.layout.one;break;

Comment: how can i add fragment to activity?